# Assigning a string from a .txt file into a variable

Tags: python, string, variables, assign

I have a .txt file with one column and about 35 rows, I have some code to assess the strings but i'm unsure how to assign each string as a variable to have it  as

[imported variable] = [rest of code]

So far i have:

```
import numpy as np
np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\...\x.txt", delimiter ='\n')
dtype=str
with open('C:\Users\...\x.txt') as f:
lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

If I `print lines` I get a nice list of all the rows but don't know where to go  from here!

Comment: `for line in lines: print line` then you can assign it to a variable, a key in a dictionary or an index in a list. :)

Comment: So this has made a list for me. Say I want to name my first row sequence_1, how do I go about that? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is @limelights answer:

```
import numpy as np
np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\...\x.txt", delimiter ='\n')
dtype=str
with open('C:\Users\...\x.txt') as f:
lines = f.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

you can make it do what you want at this point. like create a dictionary

```
new_dictionary = {}
count = 0
for line in lines:
    count += 1
    new_dictionary['sequence_{}'.format(count)] = line
```

or create a list

```
new_list = []
for line in lines:
    new_list.append(line)
```

or whatever your heart desires. welcome to SO  :)

UPDATE:
 to test your code you can print the variable with this:

```
print new_dictionary['sequence_3']
```

Comment: Ah! I think a dictionary is what I was looking for. From that I can let each row become sequence_{x}, and then can use those as variables right? Thank you!

Comment: yup, no problem man. you call the dictionary item with `dictionary_name['variable_name']`. hope that helps.

Comment: I think I messed up haha. I can call each sequence, but it calls the entire list. If I print say sequence_1 as upper case the entire list appears as upper case?

Comment: make sure your variable is line and not lines. so like this `new_dictionary['sequence_{}'.format(count)]= line` and NOT `new_dictionary['sequence_{}'.format(count)]= lines`. my guess is that this is where the problem is.

Comment: no problem, glad it worked. just a reminder, if the problem is solved, marking the green check mark by the answer lets others know the solution worked. its helpful later on when searching other posts. good luck with your future pythoning  :)